# Having trouble connecting to a MySQL database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php file that holds my login details named "connect.php".

```
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $database = 'database';
```

And I'm trying to connect with another file (html) with this as its contents:

```
    $a = file_get_contents("http://example.com/folder/connect.php");
    echo ($a);
    mysql_connect ("$host", "$username", "$password");  
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
```

And it keeps on giving me this error:

```
    Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access
    denied for user '**wrong username**'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
    /home/path/public_html/repo/path/downloads.php on line 40
```

Comment: Where are you assigning values to `$host`, `$username`, and `$password`?

Comment: your script could not output that error, since you're not doing `or die(mysql_error())` with the connect call. Is that the remote script you're fetching via file_get_contents, perhaps? You need to show the code in `/folder/connect.php` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$a = file_get_contents("http://example.com/folder/connect.php");
echo ($a);
```

You should be using [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)/[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

```
require_once '/folder/connect.php';
```

Your current code still won't work using HTTP since you'd need to eval or parse the result to assign your `$username` and `$password` variables, just outputting the result of the PHP script doesn't assign any variables.

You shouldn't need to (or be able to) use http to download your MySQL connection information through HTTP especially with no authentication. That is a big security issue. If that is your setup you should change it, so that you have a local configuration file stored outside of your web root which has your db host, username, and password in it.

Comment: Ya I'm just using example.com instead of my domain. The downloads.php file is located at example.com/folder/folder/folder/downloads.php and the connect.php is located at example.com/folder/connect.php

Comment: @Intecpsp Try `require_once __DIR__ . '/../connect.php';`, or if you're using PHP < 5.3 then `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../connect.php';`

Comment: @Intecpsp But preferably you should move the file called connect.php outside of your web root entirely (This would mean above the directory where the rest of your website files are, sometimes it's called www or public_html). It shouldn't be web accessible unless you want users to access it directly.

Comment: So if I move it to the root of the directory and do: require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/connect.php That should work?

Comment: @Intecpsp Your connect.php should be outside of public_html since you don't want your website visitors to go to it directly. Then you can use require_once to require the file using a relative path. So say you make a new folder at the same level as public_html and call it config and then put connect.php inside it. You'll use `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../config/connect.php';` to include it from `public_html/folder/folder/folder/downloads.php`

Comment: @Intecpsp `dirname(__FILE__)` will be the path to your current file (downloads.php), then you can use `../` to move up the directory tree and navigate to the file. Or you can use an absolute path like `require_once '/config/connect.php'`

Comment: I would prefer an absolute path, since then you don't have to take care about the relative constellations of both php files.

Comment: @Daxcode Try it out. Let me know if it works or if you get another warning or something.

Comment: so: require_once dirname(/public_html/folder/folder/downloads.php) . '/connect.php'

Comment: @Intecpsp Don't use dirname for an absolute path. Just `require_once '/config/connect.php';` with your connect.php file in a folder called config which is at the same level in your directory structure as public_html. Let me know what that says.

Comment: Warning: require_once(/config/connect.php) [href='function.require-once'>function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/iuser/public_html/repo/test/downloads.php on line 38

Comment: I used: require_once '/home/iuser/config/connect.php'; and it worked! Thanks @PaulP.R.O.

Comment: Okay, now try `require_once '/home/iuser/config/connect.php';` If that doesn't work, add this line to downloads.php and tell me what it says: `echo ini_get('include_path');` (It's just for information for me to help you get this working).

Comment: Care to help me here too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914303/select-certain-mysql-fields-and-display-them-using-php

Comment: @Intecpsp Sure, I just answered there for you. BTW, on Stack Overflow when an answer helps you it is normal to click the check mark under the vote count beside that answer. That set's the check mark to green and awards the user who wrote the answer some reputation for helping you. You can only accept one answer for every question you ask.

Answer (score -1):

you should use `include` instead of `file_get_contents` in order to get the `connect.php` interpreted as a php file:

> include '/path/to/connect.php';

Comment: include wont work for an http path it only works for relative paths

Comment: you should not handle your database credentials through http, as already mentioned by PaulP.R.O. it's a big security issue and would also take a huge network bandwidth in order to grab the file for each connection. Therefor I'd recommend you, to put the file in a relative path to your application in order to use it through the include or the require_once statement.