# Select certain MySQL fields and display them using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

So what I want to do is I want to search for a certain name in a column called 'filename' and display the 'count' on that row.

This might help explain:

I want to search for Packages in the 'filename' column but I want to display the 'count' on it (4)

**id       filename       count**

1        Packages         4

2        Another          7

Comment: This question is missing [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements). Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves. Read [Writing the Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filename = 'Packages';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `count` FROM `downloads` WHERE `filename` = $filename");
```

Also note that if the filename can come from user input you have to be aware of [injection attacks](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php).

```
$filename = 'Packages'; // From user

$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($filename);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `count` FROM `downloads` WHERE `filename` = $filename");
```

Here is an example that selects all Filenames and counts and lists them in a table:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `filename` `count` FROM `downloads`");
?><table><tr><td>Filename</td><td>Count</td></tr><?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $row['filename']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['count']; ?></td></tr>
    <?php
}
?></table><?php
```

Comment: Dang you're on a roll. How would I display this in a table?

Comment: @Intecpsp Do you want a table listing all the filenames and counts?

Comment: Nah I just want certain data from it and to display it on a page where people can see it.

Comment: @Intecpsp I updated my post to show an example which builds an HTML table from the results of a query. You can use `LIMIT 10` to limit it to 10 results, or ``WHERE `filename` LIKE 'P%'`` do only show files begining with a P. There are lots of things you can do. There is a good MySQL tutorial with lots of pages explaining how to do some things in MySQL here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsyntax.php There are lots of other good tutorials out there too.

Comment: Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/iuser/public_html/repo/test/downloads.php on line 44

Comment: Line 44: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT count FROM downloads WHERE filename='Packages'";
```

EDIT:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());

$arr_down = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $arr_down["count"];
```

UPDATE: For one or more rows with 'Packages' in it, you can show the results in a table like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "MySQL_username", "MySQL_password") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL Server " . mysql_error());

$fname = "Packages";

$query = "SELECT filename, count FROM downloads WHERE filename='" . $fname . "'";

$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());

$html = "<table>\n<tr><th>Filename</th><th>Count</th></tr>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    $html .= "<tr><td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td><td>" . $row['count'] . "</td></tr>\n";

$html .= "</table>\n";

echo $html;
```

Comment: Are there other rows with "Packages" in it?

Comment: No, that was just an example I used

Comment: @Intecpsp: You want to show one row only? See my update for one to many rows.

Comment: All I want to display is the filename and the count in a table

Comment: Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/iuser/public_html/repo/test/downloads.php on line 45

Comment: Line 45: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: Works with: while ($row = mysql_query($result))

Comment: Sounds like the query is wrong. Check the case of your columns and table name...?

Comment: I get no errors now but the only thing that shows up is FilenameCount

Comment: No, this is definitely wrong: $row = mysql_query($result).  Make sure your connection is ok, as well as the names of the table and columns in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you actually wants is a report of download counts for each filename, you need to use the GROUP BY clause in your SQL statement:

```
<?php

$res = mysql_query('SELECT id, filename, COUNT(*) AS count FROM downloads GROUP BY filename');

if (is_resource($res)) {
    while (false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))) {
        printf('%d - %s - %d', $row['id'], $row['filename'], $row['count']);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Okay, this one worked. BUT it is only display 1 as the download count when I can go look at the table it has 4 downloads...

Comment: My assumption was that the table only has 'id' and 'filename' as columns.  So the count was generated by counting the number of records having the same filename. Looking at the exchange between you and octern below, it seems that the table already has a column called 'count'. In such case my SQL statement miss the mark.

Comment: Ya I have an 'id' 'filename' and 'count' and what I want to show is the filename and the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result)
echo($count)
```

Check out the [PHP mysql documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) for more. In particular you'll want to learn about the fetch() functions, which you'll use to display the data you retrieve with your query.

Comment: I don't want to count the rows I want to display a column called count after searching for name in the column filename

Comment: What will the column called count have in it?

Answer (score 0):

the raw query would be:

```
select count( filename ) from downloads;
```

Edit: Okay, you want to loop them onto the page:

```
foreach( $result as $i )
{
  if( !empty( $i ) )
  {
     echo "<div>$i['column_name']</div>";
  }
}
```